# PageView, inside ListView, inside Column: `Null check operator used on a null value`

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **PageView, inside a ListView, inside a Column**. It seems necessary because of the layout (top green widget should be scrollable, but bottom widget shouldn't be).

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget createPage(int page, Color color) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 200.0),
        child: Text("Page: $page. Swipe right to go to next page"),
      ),
    );
  }

  late final List<Widget> pages = [
    createPage(1, Colors.purple),
    createPage(2, Colors.red)
  ];

  @override
  createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late final PageController _pageController;
  int page = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Text("Top of screen, scrollable.")),
              // This works
              Column(
                children: widget.pages,
              ),
              // PageView tries to take the full height. Without Flexible, PageView is unbounded.
//               Flexible(
//                 child: PageView.builder(
//                   itemCount: widget.pages.length,
//                   controller: _pageController,
//                   onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => page = index),
//                   itemBuilder: (context, index) => widget.pages[index],
//                 ),
//               )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            color: Colors.green, child: const Text("Bottom of screen, always")),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

However, I get various error based on what I try. This is an unhelpful error, since ListView doesn't have a problem when it's children is a Column:

```bash
The following _CastError was thrown during performLayout():
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView ListView:file:///path/to/project/lib/main.dart:63:18
```

---

### Code

I've created a [**Dartpad pad**](https://dartpad.dev/?id=43e60e23d7c315b2b78d834611f23272) to reproduce this. I've commented out the PageView and replaced it with a column so you can see the app. The issue is **replacing Column with 2 pages to PageView**.

[image]

---

I've tried various things:

- Wrapping ListView in things:

  - `SizedBox.expand(child: ListView(...))`
  - `Expanded(child: ListView(...))` following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62359932/7365866)
  - `Flexible(child: ListView(...))`
- `ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,...),`
- Changing mainAxisSize of `Column`

Comment: you like to divide the screen in two for single ListViewItem, and then make another scrollable at top on horizontal and bottom part fixed?

Comment: Sorry, my example is a simplification of my actual app to avoid overwhelming readers. I don't think I want to divide the screen. I want `Column[ListView[Widgets, PageView], Widgets]`.

Comment: what will be the height of `PageView`?

Comment: `PageView` should be as big as it's contents. It would change based on the content.

Comment: Can we use Different widget instead of PageView

Comment: Sure, I only used PageView because it supports swiping pages 

Comment: Is it necessary to track index ?

Comment: The index is just used to build the page. It might be useful for numbering the pages.

Comment: Can hou try wrapping the PageView inside ViewPort widget? I haven't tested it but can you give it a try?